# Clojure: How to find out the arity of function at runtime?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

Given a function object or name, how can I determine its arity? Something like `(arity func-name)` .

I hope there is a way, since arity is pretty central in Clojure

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The arity of a function is stored in the metadata of the var.

```
(:arglists (meta #'str))
;([] [x] [x & ys])
```

This requires that the function was either defined using `defn`, or the `:arglists` metadata supplied explicitly.

Comment: Note, that this really only works for functions defined with defn. It does not work for anonymous functions defined with fn or #().

Comment: As far as I can see it works for all builtin functions too. For example (:arglists (meta #'+)) or (:arglists (meta #'println))

Comment: core functions fall into the "defn" category. For example (def my-identity1 (fn [x] x)) will not work, while (defn my-identity2 [x] x) will work. defn sets :arglists for you in the metadata. core functions either use defn or set :arglists manually. Note: it does also *not* work for multimethods. You have to set :arglists manually there: (defmulti my-method {:arglists '([foo bar])} (fn [& args] (vec (map type args)))). So relying on :arglists is flawed at best.

Answer (score 51):

Sneaky reflection:

```
(defn arg-count [f]
  (let [m (first (.getDeclaredMethods (class f)))
        p (.getParameterTypes m)]
    (alength p)))
```

Or :

```
(defn arg-count [f]
  {:pre [(instance? clojure.lang.AFunction f)]}
  (-> f class .getDeclaredMethods first .getParameterTypes alength))
```

Comment: This seems to be the only option for anonymous functions, but I don't like the assumption that the first declared method is the invoke method. I would change `(first (.getDeclaredMethods (class f)))` to instead be
`(first (filter #(= "invoke" (.getName %)) (.getDeclaredMethods (class f))))`

Answer (score 6):

My heart bled (covered all the cases).

```
(defn arity
  "Returns the maximum arity of:
    - anonymous functions like `#()` and `(fn [])`.
    - defined functions like `map` or `+`.
    - macros, by passing a var like `#'->`.

  Returns `:variadic` if the function/macro is variadic."
  [f]
  (let [func (if (var? f) @f f)
        methods (->> func class .getDeclaredMethods
                     (map #(vector (.getName %)
                                   (count (.getParameterTypes %)))))
        var-args? (some #(-> % first #{"getRequiredArity"})
                        methods)]
    (if var-args?
      :variadic
      (let [max-arity (->> methods
                           (filter (comp #{"invoke"} first))
                           (sort-by second)
                           last
                           second)]
        (if (and (var? f) (-> f meta :macro))
          (- max-arity 2) ;; substract implicit &form and &env arguments
          max-arity)))))

(use 'clojure.test)

(defmacro m ([a]) ([a b]))
(defmacro mx [])

(deftest test-arity
  (testing "with an anonymous #(… %1) function"
    (is (= 1           (arity #(+ % 32))))
    (is (= 1           (arity #(+ %1 32))))
    (is (= 2           (arity #(+ %1 %2))))
    (is (= 13          (arity #(+ %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 %10 %11 %12 %13))))
    (is (= :variadic   (arity #(apply + %&))))
    (is (= :variadic   (arity #(apply + % %&)))))
  (testing "with an anonymous (fn [] …) function"
    (testing "single body"
      (is (= 0         (arity (fn []))))
      (is (= 1         (arity (fn [a]))))
      (is (= 2         (arity (fn [a b]))))
      (is (= 20        (arity (fn [a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t]))))
      (is (= :variadic (arity (fn [a b & more])))))
    (testing "multiple bodies"
      (is (= 0         (arity (fn ([])))))
      (is (= 1         (arity (fn ([a])))))
      (is (= 2         (arity (fn ([a]) ([a b])))))
      (is (= :variadic (arity (fn ([a]) ([a b & c])))))))
  (testing "with a defined function"
    (is (= :variadic   (arity map)))
    (is (= :variadic   (arity +)))
    (is (= 1           (arity inc))))
  (testing "with a var to a macro"
    (is (= :variadic   (arity #'->)))
    (is (= 2           (arity #'m)))
    (is (= 0           (arity #'mx)))))

(run-tests)
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on @whocaresanyway's solution:

```
(defn provided
  [cond fun x]
  (if cond
    (fun x)
    x))

(defn append
  [xs x]
  (conj (vec xs) x))

(defn arity-of-method
  [method]
  (->> method .getParameterTypes alength))

(defn arities
  [fun]
  (let [all-declared-methods (.getDeclaredMethods (class fun))
        methods-named (fn [name]
                        (filter #(= (.getName %) name) all-declared-methods))
        methods-named-invoke (methods-named "invoke")
        methods-named-do-invoke (methods-named "doInvoke")
        is-rest-fn (seq methods-named-do-invoke)]
    (->> methods-named-invoke
         (map arity-of-method)
         sort
         (provided is-rest-fn
                   (fn [v] (append v :rest))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it also works on macros:

```
(defn arg-count [f]
  (let [m (first (.getDeclaredMethods (class f)))
        p (.getParameterTypes m)]
    (alength p)))

(defmacro my-macro [])

(arg-count @#'my-macro)
; 2
```

Why 2? Because every macro has two implicit arguments `&form` and `&env` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

My take at the arity problem, building on the other solutions:

```
(defn arity
 "Returns the maximum parameter count of each invoke method found by refletion
  on the input instance. The returned value can be then interpreted as the arity
  of the input function. The count does NOT detect variadic functions."
  [f]
  (let [invokes (filter #(= "invoke" (.getName %1)) (.getDeclaredMethods (class f)))]
  (apply max (map #(alength (.getParameterTypes %1)) invokes))))
```

Answer (score -19):

```
user=> (defn test-func
         ([p1] "Arity was 1.")
         ([p1 p2] "Arity was 2.")
         ([p1 p2 & more-args] (str "Arity was " (+ 2 (count more-args)))))
#'user/test-func
user=> (test-func 1)
"Arity was 1."
user=> (test-func 1 2)
"Arity was 2."
user=> (test-func 1 2 3)
"Arity was 3"
user=> (test-func 1 2 3 4)
"Arity was 4"
user=> (test-func 1 2 3 4 5) ;...
"Arity was 5"
```

Comment: I don't want to *execute* the function in order to know its arity. And I don't want to change the function code for this