# Clojure: How to get meta-data of functions?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to get meta-data of all built-in Clojure functions.

In [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696693/clojure-how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-function-at-runtime) I've learned that this can be achieved using something like `^#'func_name` (get the var object's meta data).  But I didn't manage to do it programmatically, where func-name is not known in advance.

For example trying to get the metadata of the last function in clojure.core:

```
user=> (use 'clojure.contrib.ns-utils)
nil
user=> (def last-func (last (vars clojure.core)))

user=> last-func
zipmap

;The real metadata (zipmap is hardcoded)
user=> ^#'zipmap
{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name zipmap, :file "clojure/core.clj", :line 1661, :arglists ([keys vals]), :doc "Returns a map .."}

;Try to get programmatically, but get shit
user=> ^#'last-func
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name last-func, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 282}
```

How can it be done? I tried numerous variations already, but nothing does the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a looking for `meta` and `ns-resolve`.

```
user=> (let [fun "map"] (meta (ns-resolve 'clojure.core (symbol fun))))
{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name map, :file "clojure/core.clj", :line 1705, :arglists ([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls]), :doc "Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the\n  set of first i tems of each coll, followed by applying f to the set\n  of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is\n  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function\n  f should accept number-of-colls arguments."}
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, ^(ns-resolve 'clojure.core last-func) achieves this

Comment: I found another way to do this using the "intern" function: ^(intern 'clojure.core last-func)

Comment: This is a dangerous solution:
<pre><code>user=> (meta (intern 'clojure.core (with-meta 'count :meta :data})))
{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name count, :meta :data}</code></pre>

So be careful where your symbol comes from. I would still recommend ns-resolve over intern.

Answer (score 3):

Technically functions cannot have metadata in Clojure currently:

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/94-GC--Issue-90---%09-Support-metadata-on-fns

However, vars which are bound to functions may, and it looks like that's what you're finding with ns-resolve. (meta last-func) would work too. Since last-func is the var itself, ^#'last-func (which is shorthand for (meta (var (quote last-func)))) has a redundant var dereferencing.

Comment: No. (meta last-func) doens't work. Try it yourself and see. It returns nil

Comment: `clojure.contrib.ns-utils/vars` returns a list of symbols rather than a list of vars, that's why it doesn't work.